# Zend framework 1 flash messenger yields empty array

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to set a message in Zend Framework 1's flash messenger. Then I'm outputting the result here as I was getting nothing in my view:

```
public function successAction()
{
    $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage('Account has been successfully created.');
    $this->view->messages = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages();
    var_dump($this->view->messages); exit;
}
```

..but it's just an empty array.  Is there anything else I have to do withing the framework, or with the helper to set and retrieve these?

Here is how I was trying to access it from

Comment: I think it's `FlashMessenger` not `flashMessenger` that might be an issue or try this `$this->_helper->FlashMessenger('Account has been successfully created.');` in place of `$this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage('Account has been successfully created.');`

Comment: Actually, it seems it only works with a _redirect. I was doing a _forward. I've changed it to a redirect and my messages are now there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The FlashMessenger helper allows you to pass messages that the user
>   may need to see on the next request. To accomplish this,
>   FlashMessenger uses Zend_Session_Namespace to store messages for
>   future or next request retrieval.

You can see it in the [doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger)

So your message can be recovered in another action (other request).

If you want to retrieve the message in the same action, you can try to use `getCurrentMessages()`:

```
$this->view->messages = this->_helper->flashMessenger->getCurrentMessages();
```

But if this message is only for one request, you can use [Zend_Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.registry.using.html)